# How count works in 8085 Processor?

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

```
 MVI D,10H
 LXI H,4500
 LXI B,4600
 l1: MOV A,M
 STAX B
 INX H
 INX B
 DCR D
 JNZ l1
 RST 1
 hlt
```

Can any one help me to understand how loop works i.e, how count becomes zero and why is D value 10H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of loops in 8085 is that they are executed when there is a flag(decision).
in your example the program will execute normally until;**DCR D**
Then the **jnz** flag will be checked if contents in D > 0.
The program will go back to **mov A, M**.
This process will stop when D == 0.
As you know DCR is decrementing.